# Unknown object in backup file in MySQL 5.1.41-3 ubuntu12.10

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, administration

I am restoring mysql backup file which is of size 2.6GB...but while restoring I am getting  "Unknown object in backup file" exception . How can i solve this problem. and there are no logs in mysql administrator.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Seems similar to [the post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291369/what-would-lead-to-an-unknown-object-in-backup-file-problem-when-restoring-a-b)

The solution described in that bug is to increase the `max_allowed_packet` in the MySQL server configuration.

Comment: i increased the max_allowed_packet size to 1024M but problem remains same in ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have any BLOB field in your tables?

Comment: There are many other solutions as well given in the SO link. read it fully, may be your problem will be solved through some of those...

Comment: Did you restarted your MySQL server again after changing the value?

Comment: yes i have blob fields in my tables. also i have restarted my mysql after increasing packet size.